# OSX opens all recent apps and files after logging in from a lock screen

Tags: macos, login-screen

I've noticed that every other day or so after a stepping away from my MBP (mid 2014, OSX 10.11.6) and logging back in, all of my recent apps and documents will be opened, even though they were not when I stepped away. It usually happens when I close my lid, but have seen it happen when lid is left open, and it's been going on for past several months. It's an odd problem to Google as results are all over the place. Has anyone faced a similar issue or is there a known bug related to this? I have all my updates and I've tried restarting my laptop. I have no items listed in "login items".